# Disable log errors from only one module

Tags: magento-1.9

We have the option of completely disable the log errors in the backend. but is there any way we can stop getting var log errors from the particular module?

Means I don't want to see any log errors of that module under `var/log.....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to install this extension: https://github.com/jayelkaake/logmanager